# SQL SELECT records within 30 miles by latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table with the following structure:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
  ID   |  Username  |  Time  |  Latitude   | Longitude
-------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  User 1    |        |   51.4235   |  0.2171
  2    |  User 2    |        |   52.7235   |  -0.2171
  3    |  User 3    |        |   41.4235   |  0.2171
  4    |  User 4    |        |   51.43     |  0.23
```

I would like to create a MySql string to get records only within 30 miles radius from these Latitude and Longitude: 51.5235, 0.245

The SQL query doesn't seem working for me

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Longitude BETWEEN a AND c AND Latitude between b AND  d
```

Is there any way I can make SQL to calculate radius from 51.5235, 0.245 and get all users within 30 miles from database?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What's wrong with, say, the haversine formula?

Comment: The radial distance would need you to compute sqrt( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )

Comment: @Strawberry can you show me an example please?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Can you please show me this on SQL query